# Why do I get an error installing pandas on Linux (NAS)?

Tags: python, linux, pandas, nas, synology

I have been trying to have my Python scripts operational on my Synology server. So far, I managed to install necessary libraries such as requests, bs4 and cython. That works. But I am stuck with numpy and pandas, which return the following error output.

It is not pip-related (which is suggested in another question on Stackoverflow), as I already use the most recent version.

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: Python 3.8 installed

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-cbb90c2z/overlay --no-warn-script
-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_ver
sion=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy
==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''

       cwd: None

  Complete output (87 lines):

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment

  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment

  Collecting setuptools

    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)

  Collecting wheel

    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)

  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21

    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)

  Collecting numpy==1.17.3

    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)

  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy

    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started

    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'
"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-caq_alpn

         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/

    Complete output (14 lines):

    Running from numpy source directory.

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py", line 443, in <module>

        setup_package()

      File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py", line 422, in setup_package

        from numpy.distutils.core import setup

      File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 26, in <module>

        from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \

      File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 20, in <module>

        from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest

      File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 31, in <module>

        import distutils.cygwinccompiler

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cygwinccompiler'

    ----------------------------------------

    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy

    Running setup.py clean for numpy

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'
"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all

         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy

    Complete output (10 lines):

    Running from numpy source directory.

    `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

      - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)

      - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch

                          files that aren't checked into the git repo)

    Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

    ----------------------------------------

    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy

  Failed to build numpy

  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy

      Running setup.py install for numpy: started

      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'

      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

       command: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'
"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-l0tp9bsn/install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-cbb90c2z/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-cbb90c2z/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy

           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/

      Complete output (23 lines):

      Running from numpy source directory.

      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install

      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source

                                 release)

        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)

      Traceback (most recent call last):

        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

        File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py", line 443, in <module>

          setup_package()

        File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py", line 422, in setup_package

          from numpy.distutils.core import setup

        File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 26, in <module>

          from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \

        File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 20, in <module>

          from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest

        File "/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 31, in <module>

          import distutils.cygwinccompiler

      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cygwinccompiler'

      ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip
-install-ltbznc4c/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-r
ecord-l0tp9bsn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-cbb90c2z/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-cbb90c2z/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full
 command output.

  ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/bin/python3 /var/packages/py3k/target/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-en
v-cbb90c2z/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'A
IX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and pla
tform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'
"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstaled pip:

```
easy_install -U pip
```

And then installed pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your NAS does not have an x64 cpu and pip cannot find numpy for your cpu architecture.
So you need a wheel of numpy that is cross compiled for your cpu.

Your log shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cygwinccompiler'` as it tries to compile the wheel at installation time.
There is no build toolchain installed on your NAS, so you need to cross compile the wheel on another system.

You can find a cross build environment in https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc.
There you can find numpy under https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/tree/master/cross/numpy.

To get an allready compiled wheel of numpy you might download an installation package (spk) that includes numpy (i.e. home assistant core on https://synocommunity.com/package/homeassistant) and extract the wheel from the package.
Therefore you can use 7-Zip (or other packer) to extract package.tgz from the spk file.
Within package.tgz you find the wheel under share/wheelhouse (currently numpy-1.19.2-cp38-none-any.whl).
Hint: ignore the "none-any" in the wheel name, as in fact it is cross compiled for the spk specific cpu arch.

Finally copy the wheel to your NAS and install it with
`pip install numpy-1.19.2-cp38-none-any.whl`